# Printing an error object in javascript

Tags: javascript, error-handling

When throwing an Error object in my promise chain, i attach a "details" property to it so that the handler can know what to do with it in the eventual catch block.

If logging is enabled, what i do in part of the chain is log the error and then rethrow it like so :

```
.somePartOfThePromiseChain
.catch(err => {
            console.log("ERROR");
            console.log(err.details);
            debugger;
            throw err;
          });
```

This works fine however, if i wanted to print the entire Error i dont get an object as expected but something that looks different like so :

```
Error: My error description here
    at API.js:105
    at <anonymous>
```

while i was expecting a collapsable object format as per usual in Chrome dev tools.

Im not sure why this happens as i essentially just want to print the Error object and view its members when debugging. This has nothing to do with me rethrowing the error as you can imagine.

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: In the above you're logging `err.details`, not `err`, but your description makes it sound like you're talking about logging `err`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`console.dir` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/dir), [Chrome devtools docs](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/console-reference#dir)) does that on most consoles:

```js
try {
  const e = new Error();
  e.details = "details go here";
  throw e;
} catch (ex) {
  console.dir(ex);
}
```

```html
(Look in the real console.)
```

Comment: I thought log wasnt a string representation, turns out it varies depending on the object. Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 5):

Try wrapping it in another object.

Something like:

```
console.log( {error} );
```